# Why I get a error as CMException in thread main?

Tags: java

This is a program which allows user to input a year and return corresponding year in Roman numerals.I can compile it without any errors but when I run it it gets an error.

**I get an error when I run this program like this,**
[image]

**The code of this program is,**

```
import java.io.*;
public class RomanCal {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    int year;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter a year to convert : ");//asking for input
    year = input.read();

    start(year);
}

public static void start(int year){
    String full = Integer.toString(year);//full year is converted to a String
    String check = full.substring(0,1);

    switch (check){//checking the first number
    case "1" : System.out.println("M");
    break;
    case "2" : System.out.println("MM");
    break;
    default : System.out.println("Invalid Year");
     }

    check = full.substring(1,2);

    switch (check){//checking the second number
    case "0" : 
        check = full.substring(2,3);
        switch (check){//check the third number if second is zero
        case "0" :
            check = full.substring(3,4);
            switch (check){//check the fourth number if third is zero
            case "1" : System.out.print("I");
            break;
            case "2" : System.out.print("II");
            break;
            case "3" : System.out.print("III");
            break;
            case "4" : System.out.print("IV");
            break;
            case "5" : System.out.print("V");
            break;
            case "6" : System.out.print("VI");
            break;
            case "7" : System.out.print("VII");
            break;
            case "8" : System.out.print("VIII");
            break;
            case "9" : System.out.print("IX");
            break;
            }
            break;



        case "1" : System.out.print("X");
        break;
        case "2" : System.out.print("XX");
        break;
        case "3" : System.out.print("XXX");
        break;
        case "4" : System.out.print("XL");
        break;
        case "5" : System.out.print("L");
        break;
        case "6" : System.out.print("LX");
        break;
        case "7" : System.out.print("LXX");
        break;
        case "8" : System.out.print("LXXX");
        break;
        case "9" : System.out.print("XC");
        break;
        }
        break;



    case "1" : System.out.print("C");
    break;
    case "2" : System.out.print("CC");
    break;
    case "3" : System.out.print("CCC");
    break;
    case "4" : System.out.print("CD");
    break;
    case "5" : System.out.print("D");
    break;
    case "6" : System.out.print("DC");
    break;
    case "7" : System.out.print("DCC");
    break;
    case "8" : System.out.print("DCCC");
    break;
    case "9" : System.out.print("CM");
    break;
    }


    check = full.substring(3,4);

    switch (check){//check the fourth number
    case "1" : System.out.print("I");
    break;
    case "2" : System.out.print("II");
    break;
    case "3" : System.out.print("III");
    break;
    case "4" : System.out.print("IV");
    break;
    case "5" : System.out.print("V");
    break;
    case "6" : System.out.print("VI");
    break;
    case "7" : System.out.print("VII");
    break;
    case "8" : System.out.print("VIII");
    break;
    case "9" : System.out.print("IX");
    break;
    }





}


}
```

Comment: I don't see `break` statements in you switch/case

Comment: `year = input.read();` should be `year = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();`

Comment: What do you mean by `CMException`?

Comment: By the way, you might find it easier if you specify arrays like `String[] digits = { null /* skip zero */, "I", "II", "III", "IV", ... }` and then just get an element of that, rather than using switches.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: @AndyTurner Almost certainly a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Which, of course, makes no sense given the error message, but whatever ''(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @DaveNewton that's what I thought as well, but...

Comment: @Andy Turner What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: @Nimantha A string index out of bounds? Don't look into the string before it starts (e.g., index < 0) or after it ends (e.g., index >= length). Simple enough. A CMException as your post title states? Don't try to modify hashes inside a loop w/o using the iterator? No clue, nothing in your posted code should cause a CMException

Comment: @Nimantha how about doing what Lashane suggested? You might get a hint as to why your code is wrong if you print out `year` immediately after you read it. (I'm going to guess it prints `49`, the codepoint for the character `'1'`)

Comment: @DaveNewton You don't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` at all! The code prints `C`, then `M`, then it crashes with `Exception ....` leading to `CMException ...`

Comment: @Pimgd Exactly my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two main problems:

1. you're using wrong approach to read user's input, you're reading ASCII code of the first symbol ('1' = 49)
2. you're not using `break` statements in case/switch

consider following code:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
    final String[] m = {"", "M", "MM"};
    final String[] c = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    final String[] x = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    final String[] i = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
    try (final java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter a year to convert : ");
        final int year = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(m[year / 1000] + c[(year / 100) % 10] + x[(year / 10) % 10] + i[year % 10]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but I think OP would benefit from more explanation as to a) why the original code doesn't work (why these two things happen); b) how your code works.

Comment: Also: it's bad practice to close a stream you didn't open.

Comment: @AndyTurner what stream is not closed?

Comment: You are closing `System.in` via try-with-resources; you didn't open it.

Comment: @AndyTurner ah, yes, its ok for this sample